# Highlight the tableViewCell when come back from detail view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

As well know, in the "Drill In" application, the the selected table cell can be highlighted and drill in the detail view. When comes back from the detail view with "back" button touched, the selected table cell could be highlighted or not. Such as in the Apple's sample codes: **CoreDataBooks.app** and **TheElements.app**. I notice this phenomenon but don't know the reason. Yes, it's my question, how to control this phenomenon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line of code in ViewDidLoad method of the masterViewController..

```
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
```

PS: Ensure that your masterViewController is a UITableViewController Subclass.

Comment: Thanks, It works for the CoreDataBooks.app. But not work for TheElements.app with -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 [theTableView reloadData];
} in the masterViewController.

Comment: [table reloadData] does not have anything to do with the selected row. Infact, when you reload the table, the selection should disappear.
If you set the above value to YES...the selection would be cleared when you drill OUT. Similarly, a NO would cause the selection to persist.